# Mongoose push() function isn't pushing the data into the array

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose, push

I have to push a product data into a user document that has a store[] array in it,
I used the code as follow

```
const db = require("../../auth/models");
const User = db.user


exports.addProduct = (req, res) => {

  User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err })
        }else{
            console.log(user)
            user.store.push({
      
                id: req.body.id, 
                barcode: req.body.barcode,
                productName : req.body.productName,
                price : req.body.price,
                quantity: req.body.quantity
            
        })
        }
    } )

  

    
    res.status(200).send({ message: "Product updated successfully!!"})
};
```

when I console.log(user) it gave me the user data found and console.log(req) gave me the input which was given in form I can't get my head around this problem. Anything else if you require to solve the issue let me know in the comments I will post them. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you give the data structure for user and req?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine: you're finding your user in your database and you're pushing a new store in its document's .store array. But you're not saving the user document afterward. You need to use Mongoose's method .save() and only after that action is completed successfully, send your response:

```
User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err })
    }else{
        console.log(user)
        user.store.push({
  
            id: req.body.id, 
            barcode: req.body.barcode,
            productName : req.body.productName,
            price : req.body.price,
            quantity: req.body.quantity
        
        })
        user.save(function(err, newUser) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send({ message: err });
            } else {
                console.log(newUser);
                res.status(200).send({ message: "Product updated successfully!!"})
            }
        })
    }
})
```